# Type Error 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

When I try to put a border on my newly edited image, it comes up with this error. The error comes from this line of code.

```
img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(imgred,border=25,fill='red')
```

Does anyone have a fix? (I am a noob at python.)

```
def family():
q1=raw_input('What is the directory of your image? : ')
q2=raw_input('Which of these best fits you?: Christian, Patriot, or Satanist? : ')
q3=raw_input('What is the width of your frame? : ')
filename = (q1)
img = plt.imread(filename)
# Read the image data into an array
imgred = plt.imread(filename)
img = plt.imread(filename)
imgpat = plt.imread(filename)
imgblue = plt.imread(filename)
imggreen = plt.imread(filename)
imggrey = plt.imread(filename)
height = len(imgred)
width = len(imgred[0])
if q2 == 'Satanist':
    for c1 in range(height):
        for c2 in range(width):
            imgred[c1][c2][1]=0
            imgred[c1][c2][2]=0
            r=abs(imgred[c1][c2][0]-255)
            g=abs(imggreen[c1][c2][1]-255)
            b=abs(imgblue[c1][c2][2]-255)
            imgred[c1][c2]=[r,g,b]
            r=abs(imgred[c1][c2][0]-255)
            g=abs(imggreen[c1][c2][1]-255)
            b=abs(imgblue[c1][c2][2]-255)
            imgred[c1][c2]=[r,g,b]




def give_image():
img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(imgred,border=25,fill='red')              
# Create figure with 3 subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)
# Show the image data in a subplot
ax[0].imshow(img, interpolation='none')
ax[1].imshow(imgred, interpolation='none')
ax[2].imshow(img_with_border, interpolation='none')
```

MCVE: 
When I try to add the border to an already edited picture, the error comes up.
Example:

```
image_file = ('woman.jpg')
filename = 'C:/Users/Dylan/woman.jpg'
imgred = plt.imread(filename)
height = len(imgred)
width = len(imgred[0])

for c1 in range(height):
    for c2 in range(width):
        imgred[c1][c2][1]=0
        imgred[c1][c2][2]=0

def give_image():
img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(imgred,border=25,fill='red')              
# Create figure with 3 subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# Show the image data in a subplot
ax.imshow(imgred, interpolation='none')
```

But when it is a picture that is not edited and I try to add the border, there is no error.

```
image_file = ('woman.jpg')
filename = 'C:/Users/Dylan/woman.jpg'
img = plt.imread(filename)
img = Image.open('woman.jpg')
img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(img,border=25,fill='violet')

def give_image():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    # Show the image data in a subplot
    ax.imshow(img_with_border, interpolation='none')
```

The error itself.

```
235     "Add border to image"
236     left, top, right, bottom = _border(border)
--> 237     width = left + image.size[0] + right
238     height = top + image.size[1] + bottom
239     out = Image.new(image.mode, (width, height), _color(fill, image.mode))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the error is in `ImageOps.expand`, run this in your interpreter:

```
help(ImageOps.expand)
```

It will tell you how to use the function, and that should help you understand your misconception about it.

Namely, judging by the error, in particular `left, top, right, bottom = _border(border)`, it looks like it is trying to get 4 values from the `border` argument. This is also why it's failing to get an item from border, i.e. run the method `__getitem__`.

Basically you need to change the `border` argument to a list of 4 things -- the left, top, right and bottom border sizes.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that now.

Comment: I'm back...  How would I go about changing the border argument into a list of 4 things?

Comment: @DZapza It needs to return a list: `return left, top, right, bottom`

Comment: Well... that depends on what you want the border to be, doesn't it? If you want it to be 25 all around then I presume `[25, 25, 25, 25]` would work, which you can write more succinctly as `[25]*4`. If my answer has fixed your original bug, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: I think I am doing it wrong because it is not working. Could you by any chance give me a coded example?

Comment: You simply have to replace the bad line, as `img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(imgred,border=[25]*4,fill='red')`. Are you saying you are still getting the same error, having done that?

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting the same error and I did it right.

Comment: And what did `help` say?